# Specifying the static files in appengine-web.xml, What is the purpose? What values does it add?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm just learning about GAE and very new to this.

What is the purpose of specifying the static files in appengine-web.xml file, Does it add any values?

I went through the below link, but I could not actually catch the actual purpose.

[Link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google app engine has special servers to serve static files so you don't really use your instances to serve them and you are only charged the bandwidth for these.

Comment: Sorry I could not get you exactly. Do you mean that bandwidth for static files will not be charged?

Comment: Ohh I meant only bandwidth is charged and you won't need to spawn instances(has hourly rate) to serve these static files. So it's like a built-in cdn, if you wanted to serve the static files outside of these servers you would have to create a handler that serves your files and would have to spawn instances just to serve static files.

Comment: Does all the web application create these kind of instances or this is very specific to GAE?

Comment: it's specific to gae, if you would have to do it in another PaaS they probably will have their own way of serving static files but from my experience on another PaaS there isn't one and I just serve it through python webserver which isn't efficient, but you could point a cdn to it and do the versioning yourself, which on gae you could do with their wildcard subdomains which I have a tutorial for but on python, but same idea here: http://blog.altlimit.com/2013/07/cookie-less-domain-and-static-files.html